# How to deploy latest JanusGraph version on AWS with DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, graph-databases, janusgraph

I want to deploy the latest JanusGraph version on AWS with DynamoDB as backend storage.
I went through the JanusGraph documentation and I didn't found any setting for DynamoDB in backend storage settings.
I found one documentation https://bricaud.github.io/personal-blog/janusgraph-running-on-aws-with-dynamodb/ but here they are using amazonlabs repo which is using the old JanusGraph version (i.e JanusGraph 0.2). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The AWS labs project contains the official documentation for running JanusGraph on AWS DynamoDB. However, a DynamoDB backend is not officially supported by JanusGraph, hence it is counted as one of the "3rd party storage adapters for JanusGraph" according to the [JanusGraph home page](https://janusgraph.org/).

Note that this links to the [AWS Labs github repo](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-janusgraph-storage-backend). [The AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.TitanDB.html) refers to that repo as well.

This being the case, it is safe to assume that this solution is no longer being actively maintained. Issues raised in the AWS Labs repo regarding [Tinkerpop 3.3.x or 3.4.x compatibility](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-janusgraph-storage-backend/issues/309) and [JanusGraph 0.4.x](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-janusgraph-storage-backend/issues/301) and [0.3.x compatibility](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-janusgraph-storage-backend/issues/295) (much less the current 0.5.x or 0.6.x) received no response. It's probably best to use a different JanusGraph backend if at all possible.